# Display hidden div after a specific html5 video period of time

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

The video plays for approximately 9 minutes. I have a hidden div below the video. I want the hidden div to display when the video reached the 8 minutes mark. Is that possible? How can I achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `timeupdate` event and check the `currentTime` property: http://jsfiddle.net/sEbwj/1/.

```
var passed = false;
document.querySelector("video").addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if(!shown && this.currentTime > 8 * 60) {
        console.log("mark passed");
        passed = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But still don't have an Idea how to use that to show the hidden div.. My div is hidden ung CSS's display:none. Sorry but im not a javascript expert.

Comment: @markyeoj: Set `div.style.display = "block";`, where `div` is your div.